# Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT not working in Android Q

Tags: android, android-10.0

I try to attach some photos (or other! document) which have made by phone camera (or other! apps - for creating documents). If I run code below to select photo, I have not seen them:

[Screenshot from the App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHNvD.png)

If I open android file explorer - photos exist:

[Screenshot directly from android file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFcAF.png)

With other folders is the same situation as with Recent, pls see attached screens:

[Screenshot from the App 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99KPZ.png)

[Screenshot directly from android file explorer 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmBZX.png)

It looks like I have not enough permissions - but what permissions I need additionaly for Android Q??

If I use any other android versions since 6.0 to 9.0 - then everything is fine! And I can browse and select all files, that I want.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode);
```

p.s.
DCIM\Camera folder please see attached screens:

[Screenshot directly from android file explorer 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffISj.png)

[Screenshot directly from android file explorer 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJL8m.png)

Comment: Dont look in Recent only. Just browse to ../DCIM/Camera

Comment: @blackapps: With other folders is the same situation. Pls. see attached screens - I modified the question

Comment: @RussiaDroneFlights In android 10 you need to implement scope storage-related codes. check this official docs. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped

Comment: Om Infowave Developers:  I need to select any! file not only image, video or audio

Comment: `Screenshot directly from android file explorer 2` If you click on Images then you dont see any? Is that what you wanna say? Reboot your emulator.

Comment: But then.. browse to ..DCIM/Camera. Do that after you enabled 'show Internal memory'  or something like that.

Comment: blackapps: "Screenshot directly from android file explorer" and "Screenshot directly from android file explorer 2" these scrrens made from file explorer app. And I can see images and can open it. 
"Screenshot from the App" and "Screenshot from the App 2" - these screens what I see with above code provided - from My app. I dont see all folders and I dont see images

Comment: You are using an emulator?  And you still did not browse to ../DCIM/Camera?

Comment: blackapps: Yes I use emyulator. And should I make screenshots of all folders in it to insure that the problem exists?

Comment: @blackapps: DCIM/Camera not exist - pls see P.S. section of the question. But the question is not about DCIM/Camera folder. The question is about all folders!

Comment: You did not find ..DCIM/Camera because your internal memory is hidden. Go to menu with three dots and enable it.

Comment: @ blackapps: Have you seen screenshots that I made for you? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffISj.png

Comment: NO. But `Screenshot directly from android file explorer 3` shows DCIM from microSD card and not from internal memory.

Comment: @ blackapps: Ohhhh... Thank you! It's my mistake :( 
Execuse me for the stupid questions. Now I see photos from camera from my App. You can add reply - and I can mark it as solution if you want?

Comment: ... or better this question should be deleted :-)

Comment: @blackapps: Yes, different folder structure: when browsing from the App (using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT) and browsing form android file explorer, is not clear for me still. 
But anyway thank you for Your help

Answer (score -3):

Have you try with ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Comment: Please, consider adding an explanation to your suggested solution.

Comment: Invalid Operation : android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT , we are talking about android 29+